# Display a list only when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, django, list, checkbox

I'm having some trouble with HTML and Javascript (which I'm still new to). I use the Django Framework to display a list in a table case : for each element of my database, I display a list, and in this first list, a new list of corresponding elements in the database.

I made a  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yd3wk61L/).

The situation :

```
<tr>
               <td>Foo</td>
               <td>Fighters<td>
               <td>Bar</td>
               <td>Baz</td>
               <td>
                   <ul>                             
                         {% for domain,terms in django_database %}
                               <li>
                               <input type="checkbox" class="listcheck"><label for="listcheck">  -  {{ domain }}</label>
                               <!-- When checkbox is checked, the following list displays -->
                                <ul>
                                   {% for object in database %}
                                       <li>{{ object }}</li>
                                   {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                               </li>
                          {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </td>
</tr>
```

This is the Javascript that I tried, shamelessly stolen from a related question.

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
{
   var box = checkboxes[i];
    box.onclick = function() 
    {
        var currentList = this.parentNode;
        var secondColumn = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("ul")[1];

        alert("My text is: " + secondColumn.textContent );
    };
}
```

Now, I can display the two HTML lists without any trouble, it works fine. But I can't manage to get a checkbox that works. Hmm.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yd3wk61L/6/ here is the JSFiddle working with your code

Comment: I have to add two things. First what Daniel said in the comments is true. When you have multiple checkboxes like this JS can open the wrong or all "div" at once. Use  `this.parent().closest(".collapse2")` or something similar to specify which div should open. And the second problem is that you are loading unnecessary Data (I don't know how big your Query is) which you won't need all the time. You maybe want to use Ajax so the Data is only loaded when the checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zg96e5a/4/) . Its a simple JS solution with a fadeToggle. The Delay of 100 is optional but it makes the hole thing more elegant.

```
<input class="collapsed" type="checkbox">The Checkbox
<div class="collapse2 collapse" style="display:none;">
   <li>hello there</li>
   <li>hello there</li>
   <li>hello there</li>
</div>

$(".collapsed").click(function(event){
    $(".collapse2").fadeToggle().delay(100);
})
```

That should do the Trick if not leave a comment.

Comment: This will show *all* details on clicking any of the checkboxes; OP needs a way of linking the checkbox with a set of details so that only the relevant one is expanded.

Comment: @DanielRoseman So adding the Keyword `this` or `this.parent().closest(".collapse2")` would help?